# The page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get this kind of error when I create a **redirect library** I named it **redirector.php** also I already run it in **autoload.php**

this is my **redirector.php**

```
class Redirector{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct(){
        //needed for every libraries
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        $userid = $this->CI->session->userdata('userid');

        if(isset($userid)){
            redirect('/rey');
        }else{
            redirect('/log_in');
        }
    }
}
```

this is my **log_in controller**

```
if($check){
    $arr = array(
        'userid' => $check->id,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($arr);
    //redirect('/rey','refresh');
}else{
    echo "<p>User does not exist</p>";
}
```

P.S I just get this kind of error when I make it in library but if I put this code in every constructor every file except **log_in.php** I didnt get an error

```
$userid = $this->session->userdata('username');
        if(empty($userid)){
            redirect('/log_in','refresh');
        }
```

edited

I got no error in redirect in my index which is **log_in** but if I set the session it didnt redirect to rey.php this is what i have done.

```
if(empty($userid) && $this->CI->uri->segment(1) != 'log_in'){
            redirect('/log_in');
        }else{
            if(isset($userid) && $this->CI->uri->segment(1) === 'log_in'){
                redirect('/rey');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `redirector.php` will run before all controllers.. So the code redirect will work before your login controller.. So it will redirected too many times.. Checking login on every controller is better.

If you still want use this library change your code to this..

```
class Redirector{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct(){
        //needed for every libraries
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        $userid = $this->CI->session->userdata('userid');

        if(empty($userid) && $this->CI->uri->segment(1) != 'log_in'){
            redirect('/log_in');
        }

        if(!empty($userid) && $this->CI->uri->segment(1) == 'log_in'){
            redirect('/rey');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Message: Undefined property: Redirector::$uri`

Comment: use $this->CI istead of $this... I have updated my answer

Comment: so it become like this? `$userid = $CI->session->userdata('userid');

        if(!isset($userid) && $CI->uri->segment(1) != 'log_in'){
            redirect('/log_in');`

Comment: but what if the segment is more than 1?

Comment: segment(1) is your controller name.. segment(2) is your method name.. In this case we need to check the controller is not log_in. that is  $this->CI->uri->segment(1) != 'log_in'

Comment: yes but what if it become like this? `/log_in/next/next/next`

Comment: In the above code redirect will not work if your controller is log_in. It doesn't check method or other segments.. It will afftects all methods in the controller.

Comment: I see but i have a new error can you check the edited?

Comment: Yes.. Use `empty`, `!empty` I have updated my answer.. Please try.

Comment: i already done that but I got this error **first** when I log in it doesnt redirect to rey.php I need to refresh it to redirect it **second** when im in rey.php when i unset i didnt redirect to log_in.php

Comment: Did you try `empty`, `!empty` in case of `isset`?

Comment: yes i tried it also `is_null`, `!isset`, `!$userid`, `$userid == TRUE`, `$userid === TRUE` and etc

Comment: I think the issue is not in this section. It may be in your log in method..

Comment: I tried to debug it this is my code `if(empty($userid) && $this->CI->uri->segment(1) != 'log_in'){ echo "unset";}//redirect('/log_in');` and `if(!empty($userid) && $this->CI->uri->segment(1) == 'log_in'){ echo "set"; }//redirect('/rey','refresh');` if their is a session the **log_in.php** will **echo set** but if their is no session **rey.php** will **echo unset**

Comment: Write a redirect to `/rey` after setting the session

Comment: it doesnt redirect to `/rey` automatically it need to refresh to redirect

Comment: Yes.. it doesnt redirect automatically.. write this `redirect('/log_in');` after setting section

Comment: thanks for the help sir i just adjust the condition a little bit